# Returning array via INOUT parameter without modifications

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.3 and the following functions:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cad(INOUT args text[], OUT retval int4) AS $cad$
BEGIN
    retval := 0;
    RAISE NOTICE 'cad: %', args;
END;
$cad$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dodo(in_args text[]) RETURNS text[] AS $dodo$
DECLARE
    _res    text[];
    _rv     int4;

BEGIN
    _res := in_args;
    EXECUTE 'SELECT cad($1)' USING _res INTO _res, _rv;

    RETURN _res;
END;
$dodo$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I call `cad` directly, I get expected output:

```sql
psql$ select cad(ARRAY['Quiz']);
NOTICE:  cad: {Quiz}
-[ RECORD 1 ]---
cad | ({Quiz},0)

Time: 0,319 ms
```

My expected result for the `dodo(ARRAY['Quiz'])` call is the input array without changes. But instead I receive the following error:

```sql
psql$ select dodo(ARRAY['Quiz']); 
NOTICE:  cad: {Quiz}CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT cad($1)"
PL/pgSQL function "dodo" line 8 at EXECUTE statement
ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "dodo" line 8 at EXECUTE statement
```

What is wrong here?

P.S.: I have to use `EXECUTE` as function to call will vary, code simplified for the purpose of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM cad($1)' USING _res INTO _res, _rv;
```

The return type isn't two columns of text[],int it's a record of (text[],int) which needs unwrapping.